# How to check RAID level on linux (dmraid)

Tags: centos, software-raid, terminal

I already know the RAID is a software RAID made with `dmraid` (or I assume so based on the fact that `df-h` shows `/dev/mapper/VolGroup...`, also `/dev/md0` is inactive).

I've run `dmraid -r` and get:

```
/dev/sda: ddf1, ".ddf1_disks", GROUP, ok, 1953253376 sectors, data@ 0
/dev/sdb: ddf1, ".ddf1_disks", GROUP, ok, 1953253376 sectors, data@ 0
```

But I was unable to find information of the format of results. How do I find out details of the RAID setup. Specifically level of RAID (RAID 0 or RAID 1?). Does 0 at the stand for RAID 0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

dmraid with the -s switch should get you the level.

```
dmraid -s
```

Shown under 'type'.

Oh, FYI: the md0, md1, etc. is not the RAID level, but rather the individual partition on the RAID, just like you have /dev/sd0, /dev/sd1, /dev/hd1, etc.

Comment: I did try -s but I tried using it with the group name which didn't work... That one works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

Look for the "personalities" bit.

Comment: That would work only for RAID set with `mdadmin`. Which I'm not using.